# Scraping names and addresses into a dict using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to scrape Name & address data from this company's member directory webpage:

http://mfda.ca/members/directory-of-members/

I'd like the output to be stored in a dictionary, with the key as the name of the member (i.e. 3i Financial Investment Services Inc.) and the value as their address.

I was able to append the name into the dictionary, but for some reason I can't attach their address as the key. Can anyone guide me as to how to do this?

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

url = "http://mfda.ca/members/directory-of-members/"

r  = requests.get(url)

data = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

#name
letters= soup.find_all("div", class_="col-sm-6 col-md-6")

lobbying={}
for element in letters:
    lobbying[element.b.get_text()]={}
print(lobbying)    

#addr
Addr= soup.find_all("div", class_="col-sm-6 col-md-6 p-marg")
for element in Addr:
    address=element.p.get_text()
    lobbying[element.p.get_text()]["addr"]=address
```

Comment: The number of letter tags and address tags do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend scraping the names and addresses together, and building the dict concurrently:

```
lobbying = {}
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'row member-name'})

for row in rows:
    try:
        name = row.find('div', {'class' : 'col-sm-6 col-md-6'})
        addr = row.find('div', {'class' : 'col-sm-6 col-md-6 p-marg'})
        lobbying[name.a.b.text] = {'addr' : addr.p.text}
    except AttributeError:
        pass

print(lobbying)
```

Output:

```
{
    '3i Financial Investment Services Inc.': {
        'addr': 'Suite #221, 9040 Leslie Street\nRichmond Hill, ON L4B 3M4\nPhone: (905) 597-5000\nFax: (905) 597-8366'
    },
    'ARTECH Asset Advisory Services Inc.': {
        'addr': '209 - 3993 Henning Drive\nBurnaby, BC\xa0V5C 6P7\nPhone: (604) 434-3863\nFax: (604) 434-3873'
    }
...
}
```